# Method Overriding: In Extended classes

Tags: java, inheritance, overriding

In the following code given, I understand the first part that when i call the c1.show(),it will override only the public and protected part. But I don't understand when i call c2.show(), why it is overriding the pac() as well.

```
  package P1;

  public class Base {
  private void pri( ) { System.out.println(“Base.pri()”); }
          void pac( ) { System.out.println(“Base.pac()”); }
  protected void pro( ) { System.out.println(“Base.pro()”); }
  public void pub( ) { System.out.println(“Base.pub()”); }

       public final void show( ) {
         pri();  pac();  pro();  pub(); }   
       }
```

---

```
  package P2;

  import P1.Base;

  public class Concrete1 extends Base {
   public void pri( ) { System.out.println(“Concrete1.pri()”); }
   public void pac( ) { System.out.println(“Concrete1.pac()”); }
   public void pro( ) { System.out.println(“Concrete1.pro()”); }
   public void pub( ) { System.out.println(“Concrete1.pub()”); }

    Concrete1 c1 = new Concrete1();
    c1.show( );
```

Output:

Base.pri()

Base.pac()

Concrete1.pro()

Concrete1.pub()

```
package P1;

 import P2.Concrete1;

  public class Concrete2 extends Concrete1 {
   public void pri( ) { System.out.println(“Concrete2.pri()”); }
   public void pac( ) { System.out.println(“Concrete2.pac()”); }
   public void pro( ) { System.out.println(“Concrete2.pro()”); }
   public void pub( ) { System.out.println(“Concrete2.pub()”); }
  } 


   Concrete2 c2 = new Concrete2();
   c2.show( );
```

Output:

Base.pri()

Concrete2.pac()

Concrete2.pro()

Concrete2.pub()

Comment: Yes it is Concrete2, I have edited the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, let's go.

In the definition of the class Base, the method pac() has package-private visibility, that is, it's only accessible for classes in the same package. As Concrete1 is not on the same package, it can only override the methods with public/protected visibility.

Concrete2 is at the same package of Base (P1), this explains why it can override pac() and also the difference in the output of the two cases.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to programming. But I want to know why pac() got overridden. I'm not sure about the access modifier. Isn't it is private?  And if it about the same package, then why pri() is not getting overridden.

Comment: The reason why pri() is not getting overridden is because it is with private access on the superclass Base, that is, it belongs only to Base class. As you're not overriding the method show(), when you call it on a child class, you're calling the superclass implementation. Java gives precedence of execution for methods of the superclass that cannot be overridden in this circunstance. I suggest you this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html

Comment: On the Concrete2 case, pac() got overridden because Concrete2 is in the same package as Base. In Base, the method pac() doesn't have an access modifier, so it is deafult access or package-private. In this case, because of the access modifier, only classes in the same package can override it. As Concrete1 is not on the same package, it cannot override it.